# How to predict what type of object a python with statement will return?

Tags: python, mysql, with-statement

In the python statement `with x() as y:`, what attribute or method of `x` determines the type of `y`? I've noticed that it does not have to be the type of `z` from `z = x()`. I encountered this while establishing a mysql connection.

Compare

```
import pymysql
with pymysql.connect(<db info>) as cur:
    print(type(cur))
```

to

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect(<db info>)
print(type(con))
con.close()
```

When I changed my code to use the `with` statement, it obviously broke. So how would I query the pymysql module in advance to know what object comes `with`?

Comment: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__

Comment: However, `z = x(); with y as con: ...` will work. Method calls are not treated differently inside `with`.